# stl error loading

Tags: ros, rviz, urdf, mesh, stl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to create a Robot URDF and represent it in RVIZ and I have two problems when inserting the geometry using  (when I used simple geometries the robot's representation was ok).

If the link's  is STL extension represents only some pieces of it. Also it is the same if I try whit any of the STL files of PR2 (for example head_v0.stl), only represents some lines. Why not represent STL files well? (no errors in terminal and RVIZ)

If I transform the object to Collada (.dae) exporting with the program "Blender", for example, this is represented correctly, but in white, when the object is of a different color!.

Ubuntu 11.04, ROS diamondback, stack robot_model install.

Can anyone help me with one of the two problems?

Sorry for my English, I am Spanish and I don't write/speak english very well.

The URDF robot is not the problem, but it is:

-->

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11758/stl-error-loading/) by [Rikki](https://answers.ros.org/users/1114/rikki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2011-11-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I'm understanding you correctly, when you use any STL files, you only see some lines and not the whole shape. This may be a problem with your graphics card.

If you are seeing white objects, that often means that there is no TF frame for the link. Try using a combination of JointStatePublisher and RobotStatePublisher as described in [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch).

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2011-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rikki](https://answers.ros.org/users/1114/rikki/) on 2011-11-04**:
At the end I got it! Apparently the problem that appeared white pieces was not ROS. I needed to attach the texture to the object in blender (OGRE tool). Thank you very much David. (Collada Successful!!!)

**Comment by [rukie](https://answers.ros.org/users/38027/rukie/) on 2019-04-05**:
That tutorial should include a comment about no transfer frame and the STL appearing white. That's a damn head scratcher that was driving me nuts!